# Clustering population data respecting given regional divisions?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, clustering, regionalization

I am familiar with clustering algorithms from machine learning and signal processing, for example for training vector quantisers. Recently, I have come across a problem in the GIS area that I am unfamiliar with. What if you want to cluster a land area according to population density. I.e., you have a fine-grained grid of population numbers across the area. You want to cluster this area into regions with approximately homogeneous density and you want clusters with fairly few inhabitants (but > 150) **and** you want the clusters to respect some pre-defined borders. Especially the latter constraint is important. Which approaches (if any) exist for doing this?

I have come across DBSCAN here: https://www.r-bloggers.com/geographic-clustering-of-uk-cities/. Is that a possible approach?

If possible it would be great if there is a Python implementation and/or an ArcGIS-compatible solution.

Comment: What have you tried?  What GIS software are you actually the most likely to use?  That is the option that I would recommend researching/testing first.

Comment: The problem is one I am trying to help a PhD student (not mine) with. He is the one experimenting and has tried some heuristic approaches of his own. So far he is creating the pre-defined borders based on geographical features, mainly larger roads. He then so far checks if the resulting regions are large enough (> 150 inhabitants) and is trying methods to then merge these if they are too small. He is using ArcGIS.

Comment: Our focussed Q&A format is not designed for use by a proxy asker, but the same will apply as to any question, i.e. please use the [edit] button beneath it to revise it with any requested clarifications because potential answerers are volunteers who do not always have time to read the comments.  As it stands I think this question is probably too broad.  Have he/you reviewed the [self-assembling FAQ on clustering](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clustering?sort=frequent).